# Sentence description

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical description/status/analysis of Sentences like, I reckon/I think/guess/you know/As I said/As you know /if you permit etc which are placed at the beginning of a sentence. Can they be said to be principal/subordinate  clauses of sentence of which they are part? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1.

……I……reckon/think/guess ....[insert what it is that you reckon]

Subject…………verb… ……[content/noun clause as complement.]

[…….........................main clause…………………………………]

2. As I said/As you know,……[insert statement]

[…….free modifier……]….. [….main clause…..]

3.

If you permit = subordinate conditional clause.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard, in the example of free modifier, will it be described as adverbial clause of manner  followed by principal clause if the complete sentence were to read "As you know, these days the world is facing a Pandemic" Thanks

Comment: Yes, free modifiers are usually adverbial.